# Apply `&` on a boolean array

Tags: julia

I have an array of boolean values and I want to get the logical and of all elements. What is the most efficient way to do that?

I tried

```
&([true,false,false]...)
```

but it throws the error:

```
syntax: malformed expression
```

Surprisingly (at least to me) the following expression

```
|([true,false,false]...)
```

evaluates to `true`. So how do I do that? Right now I use a bunch of nots to do that, but this is very unsatisfactory.

Also is this actually better than just looping through all the elements?

Comment: Wrap `&` in parenthesis like this `(&)([true,false,false]...)`. However, a normal way to do it is to use `all` and `any` functions, e.g. `all([true,false,false])`. The difference is that `&` and `|` are bitwise operators (so they work on `Int` etc.).

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about the existence of `all` and `any`. Thanks. I think you should write is as an answer.

Comment: There's also the option of `reduce(&, xs)`, with the difference that this will not short-circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this behavior of `&` is caused by deprecated `ccall` functionality where `&` was used in front of a variable. As explained in the comments above:

- you can wrap `&` in parentheses to make it work as expected`(&)([true,false,false]...)`; however, this is not efficient as you have do splat the passed argument;
- if your arguments are all `Boll` then `all` function is a recommended way to perform *logical and*;
- if you would need *bitwise and* then `reduce(&, [true,false,false])` is a nice solution as [phg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346276/phg) indicated.